# Adding data to an existing list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have list: `{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}`

What is the most simple (but automated) way to add this data to the list?

```
{{a, 0}, {a, b}, {c, 0}, {c, d}, {e, 0}, {e, f}}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a replacement rule like

```
{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}} /. {x_, y_} :> 
  Sequence[{x, 0}, {x, y}]
(* {{a, 0}, {a, b}, {c, 0}, {c, d}, {e, 0}, {e, f}} *)
```

Comment: Just need to be careful that the top-level list must never have only two elements, otherwise the pattern will match that.

Comment: Also, be wary of what happens when your list of ordered pairs is only two elements long. To get around that issue, use `Replace` with a level-spec: `Replace[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {x_, y_} :> Sequence[{x, 0}, {x, y}], 2]`

Answer (score 10):

A couple of other methods.  We take

```
lst = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
```

Three directly related ones:

```
Table[{j {1, 0}, j}, {j, lst}]~Flatten~1
Flatten[{# {1, 0}, #} & /@ lst, 1]
Flatten[{{#1, 0}, {#1, #2}} & @@@ lst, 1]
```

A relatively concise one using `Riffle`:

```
Riffle[# {1, 0} & /@ #, #] &@lst
```

And a somewhat silly way:

```
Hold@Sequence[# {1, 0}, #] & /@ lst // ReleaseHold
```

Or, from a comment by [Gerli](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/8389/gerli):

```
Apply[Sequence, {# {1, 0}, #}] & /@ lst
```

Comment: Slight variant for Riffle: `Riffle[ #.{{1, 0}, {0, 0}}, #] &@lst`

Comment: Instead of `Hold[Sequence[...]] // ReleaseHold` you could use `Apply[Sequence, {...}]`

Comment: also `## & @@ {{#, 0}, {##}} & @@@ lst` (+1)

Comment: @kglr. That is amazing. All operator forms!

Answer (score 4):

```
## &[{#, 0}, {##}] & @@@ lst
```

> {{a, 0}, {a, b}, {c, 0}, {c, d}, {e, 0}, {e, f}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};

Riffle[MapAt[0 &, {;;, 2}] @ list, list]
```

{{a, 0}, {a, b}, {c, 0}, {c, d}, {e, 0}, {e, f}}

Answer (score 1):

```
Splice[{{#, 0}, {##}}] & @@@ lis
```

> {{a, 0}, {a, b}, {c, 0}, {c, d}, {e, 0}, {e, f}}

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `Fold`:

```
lst = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};

Fold[Join[#1, {{First@#2, 0}, #2}] &, {}, lst]

(*{{a, 0}, {a, b}, {c, 0}, {c, d}, {e, 0}, {e, f}}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MapThread[Sequence,{Thread[List[#[[All,1]],0]],#}]&@lst

(* {{a,0},{a,b},{c,0},{c,d},{e,0},{e,f}} *)
```

Or

```
Thread[Hold[Sequence][Thread[List[#[[All,1]],0]],#]]&@lst//ReleaseHold

(* {{a,0},{a,b},{c,0},{c,d},{e,0},{e,f}} *)
```